# How to cause a window-resize event programmatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an npm package that I use to render in PDF's in React, but it renders it into a resizable column. Some parts of the PDF viewer resizes when I resize the column, but not the actual PDF view. But as soon as I resize the browser window the PDF view instantly snaps to the new width.

[image: I]

**Normal view**

[image]

**Column resized... the toolbar resizes but not the scroll bar or the PDF view**

[image]

**After I slightly change window width**

The PDF viewer obviously listens for an onWindowResize event, but short of trying to modify the PDF package or change my code fundamentally, is there a hook or a method that I can use to just trigger a window resize event without actually changing window size, that I can just add to the column resize event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [EventTarget: dispatchEvent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) method to call the `resize` event in `window`:

```js
window.addEventListener('resize', () => console.log('resize'));

setTimeout(() => window.dispatchEvent( new Event('resize') ), 1000);
```